# Kafka batch consumer without duplicate records

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, ksqldb

I have the following requirements, we are reading from a relational database with CDC insert/update on a specific table and import these as events into a Kafka topic.

e.g. jdbc-source-topic

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Timestamp      |        ID        |      Column      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        10:00        |         1        |         A        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        10:01        |         2        |         B        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        10:01        |         1        |         C        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

At the end of the pipeline we would like to consume these events once per day and to avoid duplicates for the same ID.

e.g. target-topic

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Timestamp      |        ID        |      Column      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        10:01        |         2        |         B        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        10:01        |         1        |         C        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

The best solution in my mind is to have a consumer with a group_id (so that offset is store in kafka for the next day) that run once. But this means that every time the consumer runs it has to drop duplicates from the fetched records.

Considering that this table may be used also for KSQL Joins in future, I'm wondering if it exists a better approach using KSQL queries, in order for the consumer to fetch from a cleaned topic with one record for each key.

Answer (score 0):

If the only consumer of this data is ksqlDB then you may not need to de-dup as ksqlDB will correctly handle multiple updates to the same key if you import the topic as a TABLE in ksql, i.e. rather than doing:

```
CREATE STREAM FOO (... columns ...) WITH (...);
```

Do:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (... columns ...) WITH (...);
```

At present, when ksqlDB processes such a change log it will output all / some of the duplicates, depending on how you've configured `cache.max.bytes.buffering`.

You may be able to avoid emitting the duplicates by using a 24 hour window and the up comming [Suppress support](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/design-proposals/klip-10-suppress.md).  Until then, if you wanted to remove the duplicates as you've suggested. You may also be able to get something working by writing your own Kafka Streams app to materialize the table into a state store and use the suppress api to remove the duplicates.

However, it's worth pointing out that, semantically, the duplicates don't cause any problems. The result of materializing the changelog into a table is 
correct with and without the duplicates.  So, as I said at the start, removing duplicates may not even be necessary.

Comment: But as far as I know to create a table from a stream I need a group by expression, considering that the table has the same columns of the stream the only solution would be to group by every column with a final count, but this doesn't drop duplicates at the key level only at the row level. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm suggesting you don't start by importing your topic as a stream, but import it as a table, i.e. use CREATE TABLE, not CREATE STREAM to import your data.